# Which monitor is active?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I run my application under the primary monitor and sometimes under the secondary monitor/TV.

And that application does a screenshot.

The question is how I can know **which monitor IS CURRENT: primary or secondary do generate** A SCREENSHOT?

Have I use some of the those things?

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X 
Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.X
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current"? Windows has no notion of one monitor or the other being "current". One monitor *is* designated "primary", but that's mainly for [backwards compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/20/10052248.aspx).

Comment: @JoeWhite Good point man! Thanks I will read it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Screen.FromControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol.aspx)

```
bool isOnPrimaryMonitor = Screen.FromControl(this).Primary;
```

For WPF, use [`Screen.FromHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromhandle.aspx), where `this` is a `Window`:

```
Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
```

Comment: Question: How do I can use "this" in Screen.FromControl(this).Primary; for the WPF application?

Comment: But also could you answer please: If we have Screen.AllScreens.Count = 10 monitors then how we can know which of them is active? IE if the some application lives under monitor #5 ?

Comment: They would all be active, otherwise they wouldn't appear in the AllScreen enumeration. If 1 screen was not active in your scenario, the count of screens would be 9. But if you have a specific application, and you want to know which screen it is on, then use the handle from the main window, i.e. `Process.MainWindowHandle`, or other child window.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you
[Multi-monitor-programming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6471/Multi-monitor-programming-in-C)